# Install SharePoint Search application Issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, installation

If i want to install SharePoint Search application , what should i prefer ? Whether to install it on Single Tier Server(Application and Database on same server ) or Multi-Tier Server(Application and Database on Different Server)?

Kindly provide the Possible reason.

Comment: Any kind of help will be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're planning a test/development system that would not be used in production, I'd always recommend that the installation is multi-tier.

This allows much greater flexibility later should expansion of the solution be required, as you can add an additional server without either spending time separating the SQL and application roles, or ending up with servers that are not loaded in the same way, as well as allowing tuning of each part of the system (SQL, application) separately.

Comment: Can you please suggest any microsoft or technet link which is suggesting the same .

Comment: Have a look at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=286978 (streamlined topologies for SharePoint 2013; PDF file) which shows some example farm topologies. Notice that the singe server with all roles is only recommended for evaluation and very light and simple workloads (which search is not!)

Comment: Hello andy , we are using one sharepoint server for search purpose(Crawling data) only not doing any sharepoint activity like creating site and all . Server size has been increased from 20GB to 48GB .
But only 10% processor and 80% storage are used(Since sharepoint services and SQL services consuming lot of storage space ) , making sharepoint search performance less. What will be solution for it ? whether to move database to another server or increasing the size of server ?

Comment: Move the SQL databases to a dedicated server. Use a SQL alias on the SharePoint server to point the database connections to a different server. The crawling function of SharePoint can really hammer the server resources if it's crawling lots and lots of files!